# Fetch necessary function call arguments in Emacs

Tags: help, arguments

I started writing code in Emacs some days ago and i'm doing very well, however, a very difficult and boring situation is always annoying me, that is the moment of call a function written by me. To make the things easy i press `M-/` to auto complete the function name, but sometimes there're many necessary arguments that must be supplied and it's hard to remember, my initial approach was open a new buffer, visit the file, search where the functions is positioned and see the necessary arguments. I'd like to find any feature that fetch these arguments for me, and put them in a mini buffer or in another place. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Which programming language?  The general mechanism for *showing* you this information as you type is known as `eldoc`, and `global-eldoc-mode` has been enabled by default for a long time, but the programming mode (or some additional glue package) does need to support it.  You can see eldoc in action when editing function calls in elisp code.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't exactly what i wanted but work in the same way.

The answer would be etags, generating a file of TAGS and when necessary ask to the Emacs jump to the location of that function. The following command on terminal create the necessary TAGS file:

```
etags *.c *.h
```

after that you can `M-.`, type what you want to find in the TAGS and press `RET`. Automatically the Emacs will jump to the definition of the given name. When you need go back to the previous file now knowing the necessary arguments just do `C-x <left>` and the previous file will be shown.